# Remove multiple items from Dictionary at once

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, string>, OperationType> clickedList;
```

where OperationType is an Enum { Download, Install, Remove, Enable }

I have another KeyValuePair list like so:

```
toRemove = machine.Array
                  .Select(x => 
                      new KeyValuePair<int, string>((int)x.MachineID, x.PackageID))
                  .ToList();
```

I need to do the following:

1. Remove all items from **clickedList** that exist in **toRemove** and **OperationType != "Remove"**
2. Remove all items from **clickedList** that have **OperationType = "Remove"** and DO NOT exist in **toRemove** list.

Is there a good way of doing this? How would I do it?

Comment: When it comes ot optimization, you need to clearly define your terms. What is acceptable and what isn't, in terms of performance? What, specifically, was inefficient about the foreach loop? What do you base that judgement on?

Comment: When using a list I was able to use myList.RemoveAll(x => items.contain). Not  sure if there's a way using dictioanry

Comment: How many items in your list where you've determined a `foreach` loop is not efficient? The typical removal pattern is to iterate a collection using an indexer in reverse with a `for` loop, but I'd still prefer to instead return a new list based on a filter of the old list that excludes the items you would normally remove as this approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that the most efficient way to do that would be to use a HashSet> to store all the keys that should actually be removed from the dictionary - although this solution doesn't use linq:

```
toRemove = machine.Array
              .Select(x => 
                  new KeyValuePair<int, string>((int)x.MachineID, x.PackageID))
              .ToList();

// create a hash set and initially put all the elements from toRemove in the set
var r = new HashSet<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(toRemove);

// go over each element in the clickedList
//    and check whether it actually needs to be removed
foreach(var kvp in clickedList.Keys)      // O(n);  n = # of keys/elem. in dictionary
{
    if(kvp.Value == OperationType.Remove)
    {
       if(r.Contains(kvp.Key)             // O(1)
          r.Remove(kvp.Key);              //    (1)
       else
          r.Add(kvp.Key);                 //   O(1)
    }
}

foreach(var key in r)                     // O(m); m = # of keys to be removed 
{
    clickedList.Remove(key);
}
```

I believe the above is probably the most efficient way of removing the elements since it's linear in the number of keys in the dictionary.

Comment: ha!. very smart :). I get it!. without the first foreach you would only remove items that exist in toRemove list. But shouldn't it be this (inside the first foreach:                         if (!toRemove.Contains(kvp.Key))
                        {
                            r.Add(kvp.Key);
                        }

Comment: i think this is wrong. it removes items even though they're "Remove" op type. and it SHOULD remove items that are REMOVE and DO NOT exist in toRemove

Comment: @ShaneKm - it looks like I miss-interpreted your question. I thought you wanted to remove all items that were in `toRemove' as well as all items from `clickedList` that were operation `Remove'. But it sounds like you don't want to remove any elements that were both in `toRemove` and had the operation `Remove` in `clickedList`. Is that right?!

Comment: 1. I need to remove all items from clickedList that (have OperationType <> Remove) && (are in toRemove list). 2. Remove all items from clickedList that (have OperationType == Remove) and (are NOT in toRemove list)

Comment: @ShaneKm - then please see update. that should work as you described. Essentially the modification happens in building the set within the foreach.